# How do I update and insert recent scores of a typing test into a text file using VSC?

Tags: javascript, stack, local-storage

In our typathon app, we want to store the WPM and accuracy of most recent 10 games of that user (according to their login username) into their own txt file. However with the coding logic now, the program duplicates the WPM and accuracy into 2 index of the txt file. Example:

(username), (password), (average WPM), (average accuracy), (best WPM), (best accuracy), (most recent game WPM), (most recent accuracy), ...... until 9 more game scores are stored.

Right now, the program stores the most recent scores into 4 slots instead of the first 2.

The code in one of the controllers:

```
private static String insertResults(String line, String username, double wpm, double acc) {
        int[] parts = convertToIntegerArray(line.split(","));
        int[] updatedParts = Arrays.copyOf(parts, parts.length);

        //parts[0] username, parts[1] password, parts[2] avg wpm, parts[3] avg acc, parts[4] best wpm, parts[5] best acc
        int avgWPM = parts[2]; int avgACC = parts[3];
        int totalWPM = 0, totalACC = 0;

        if(parts[24] != 0) { //If full, set the longest results to 0
                parts[24] = 0;
                parts[25] = 0;
            }

        for(int i = 24; i >= 8; i -= 2) { //Update 10 latest wpm and acc, odd is wpm, even is acc
            updatedParts[i] = parts[i - 2];
            updatedParts[i + 1] = parts[i - 1];
        }
        
        updatedParts[6] = (int) wpm; updatedParts[7] = (int) acc; //insert recent game wpm and acc

        for(int i = 6; i < updatedParts.length; i += 2) { //calculate average wpm and acc
            totalWPM += updatedParts[i];
            totalACC += updatedParts[i + 1];
        }

        int games = 0;
        for(int i = 6; i < updatedParts.length; i +=2) {
            if(updatedParts[i] != 0) {
                games++;
            }
        }

        avgWPM = (int) totalWPM / games ; avgACC = (int) totalACC / games ;
        updatedParts[2] = avgWPM; updatedParts[3] = avgACC;

        if(updatedParts[2] > updatedParts[4]) { //compare recent wpm and acc with best wpm and acc
            updatedParts[4] = updatedParts[2];
        }

        if(updatedParts[3] > updatedParts[5]) {
            updatedParts[5] = updatedParts[3];
        }

        return convertToString(updatedParts);
    }
```

This is the code I have now but I can't figure out the error. This code updates a line with the updated scores and values and rewrites it back into the txt file